# Where is my NSLog output?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nslog

I've just started out learning iOS development. I'm using some `NSLog` statements in my code but they don't appear to be output anywhere. My application is using the debug configuration and I'm running my application in the iPhone simulator from within Xcode. I've checked both the Xcode console (under the Run menu) and also Console.app on my Mac, but there's nothing.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that line with `NSlog` is executed? Try to insert `NSLog` right after autorelease pool allocation in `main.m`

Comment: What hoha said. Also, try doing a clean after rebooting your mac.

Comment: @hoha You were correct. For some reason the log statements in my view controller were not being executed. If you add your comment as an answer then I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Moved from comment*

Are you sure that line with `NSLog` is executed? Try to insert `NSLog` right after autorelease pool allocation in main.m

Comment: My controller code wasn't running because I had the incorrect controller assigned in an xib file.

Answer (score 21):

Make sure you have your `Console` activated. To do that, you can:

- Go to **View > Debug Area > Activate Console** (From your Menu Bar)
- Or press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> on your keyboard

Answer (score 7):

`NSLog()` output on the simulator does indeed show up in the Console Mac OS X application.

Go to `All Messages` and then filter based on your app name to get rid of the fluff, and run again. You'll see it in your output if the NSLog code is actually being hit during the execution of your program.

Comment: I found this especially useful when checking  logs for things after the initial app fired which didn't seem available in the XCode Console.

Answer (score 4):

Use `NSLog()` like this:

```
NSLog(@"The code runs through here!");
```

Or like this - with placeholders:

```
float aFloat = 5.34245;
NSLog(@"This is my float: %f \n\nAnd here again: %.2f", aFloat, aFloat);
```

In `NSLog()` you can use it like `+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...`

```
float aFloat = 5.34245;
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is my float: %f \n\nAnd here again: %.2f", aFloat, aFloat];
```

You can add other placeholders, too:

```
float aFloat = 5.34245;
int aInteger = 3;
NSString *aString = @"A string";
NSLog(@"This is my float: %f \n\nAnd here is my integer: %i \n\nAnd finally my string: %@", aFloat, aInteger, aString);
```

Comment: A great answer...but not to the question I asked.

Comment: Answers like this should not be voted down upon. Consider people take time off their day to answer and give great feedback. It might not be the specific answer, and perhaps should not be voted up, but it should not be voted down either.

Answer (score 1):

Really weird. Just for the sake of experiment: try to redirect the NSLog output to some file like this:

```
freopen ("/out","w", stderr);
NSLog(@"1234567890");
```

If there is an output, then there is something wrong with your `stderr`.